# Are Groups can be sorted other than alphabetically in JqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm getting response from server that gives data in grouping in a specific order. But when I load that data in my jqGrid it automatically sort groups in alphabetically order, and I want the order in which server provided me data.

For example I'm getting data in three groups i-e university , college , school

Now this can be sorted as increasing order i-e college , school , university

Or

Can be sorted as decreasing order i-e university , school , college

What should I do so that the order will remain in the same order as I'm getting it back from server?

I want to make some addition the response of server is stored in an object and then I load that data in a grid so I guess its local data...
Sorry I'm new to jqGrid

Here is my code for jqgrid.

```
GRID = $("#"+GRID_ID).jqGrid({
            url: sample,
            datatype: 'json',
            jsonReader : {
                        root:"rows",
                        page: "page",
                        total: "total",
                        records: "records",
                        //repeatitems: false,
                    },
            colNames: ['File', 'UID', 'Order', 'Type', 'Project','Method', 'Phase' , 'Group'],
            colModel: [{
                name: 'file',
                index: 'file',
                width: 140
            }, {
                name: 'uid',
                index: 'uid',
                width: 80
            }, {
                name: 'order',
                index: 'order',
                width: 60,
                sortable:true

            }, {
                name: 'type',
                index: 'type',
                width: 75,
                editable:true,
                edittype:"select",
                editrules: { required: true }
            }, {
                name: 'project',
                index: 'project',
                width: 100,
                editable:true,
                edittype:"select",
                editrules: { required: true }
            }, {
                name: 'method',
                index: 'method',
                width: 60,
                editable:true,
                edittype: "select",
                editrules: { required: true }, 
                //editoptions: { size: 71}
            },{
                name: 'phase',
                index: 'phase',
                width: 75,
                editable:true,
                edittype:"select",
                editrules: { required: true }
            },{
                name: 'group',
                index: 'group',
                width: 75,
                sortable: false,
                hidden:false
            }],
            loadComplete: function() {

                $("#"+GRID_ID).setColProp('type', { editoptions: { value: types} });
                $("#"+GRID_ID).setColProp('project', { editoptions: { value: project} });


            },
            //rowNum: 10,
            autowidth: true,
            rowList: [10, 50, 100],
            pager: $("#"+PAGER_ID),
            loadonce: true,
            sortname: 'order',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortOrder: "asc",
            multiSort: false,
            pgbuttons: true,
            pginput: true,          
            cellEdit: true, 

            cellsubmit : 'clientArray',
            editurl: 'clientArray',
            height: "100%",
            toolbar: [true, "bottom"],
            grouping:true,
            groupingView : { 
                groupField : ['group'],
                groupDataSorted : true,
                groupSorted:false,
                groupColumnShow:[true],
                sortable:false 
            },
            caption: 'JqGrid Examples'
        }).navGrid("#"+PAGER_ID, {
            edit: false,
            add: false,
            del: false
        });
```

Comment: It should display in the order you are receiving it from the server. Can you post your jqGrid code here so I can take a look?

Comment: Yes, you will need to post some of your code on the server production of your data.  Chances are it is sorting your data and returning it in either asc or desc based on alphabetical.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had same problem. i have solved like below.

1) Added index filed in the row

2) provided order(like 1,2,3....) for each row on server side

3) And settings in JQGrid

```
        loadonce: false,
        altRows: true,
        sortname: 'index',     /* this filed */
        sortorder: "asc",       /* this filed */
        grouping: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ['group'],
            groupColumnShow: [false],
            groupCollapse: true,
            groupSorted: false,     /* this filed */
            groupDataSorted: true  /* this filed */
        },
```

with All 4 /* this filed*/ values , we can achive this.

Suppose in your case groups(elements in group ) like university(a,b) , college(x,y,z) , school(p,q,r,s,t).

Then on server side.
(index, elment) (1,a),(2,b),(3,x),(4,y),.....(10,t).
Try this ,if didnt work let know.
Thanx.